# Output Array With UTF8 Encoding

Tags: powershell, csv, utf-8

I am running a powershell script which pulls a listing from Active Directory and writes to a CSV file. Special characters such as ó are being written as a '?' even though they are correct in Active Directory. Can I enforce UTF8 encoding?

Relevant Code:

```
$array | Select-Object Username, GivenName, Surname, Name, EmailAddress, Department, Title, ManagerName | Export-Csv -Path $csvoutput -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: add `-Encoding UTF8` as a parameter to `Export-Csv`

Comment: Excellent thank you, if you want to submit that as the answer I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Export-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) has a parameter `-Encoding`, that specifies the encoding for the exported CSV file. The default value is `ASCII` in PowerShell 5, or  `utf8NoBOM` in PowerShell 7.

Assuming you're using PowerShell 5, your code would be:

```
$array | 
    Select-Object Username, GivenName, Surname, Name, EmailAddress, Department, Title, ManagerName | 
    Export-Csv -Path $csvoutput -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```